# Return Multiple Json Objects from MVC (Ajax/Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi,

We are using **MVC/JQuery** for one web application: In one the screen users can generate charts. Now requirement as below:

1)  Select **Chart Criteria**. (Client/Date Range/Chart Axis etc)

2)  Press **“Generate”** Button… Which further makes a call to JQuery and then get the Data from Server through Ajax Call.

3)

```
public JsonResult GetDayData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,
      string clientID, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, string SortOrder))
{
    //Makes a call to Stored Procedure
    Stored procedure runs and return multiple datatables (ds.tavles[0], ds.tables[1] etc.
}
```

4)  Based on these datatables we need to **refresh/create** 4-5 charts (assuming 4-5 datatables will be returned from stored procedure)

5)  I am able to `return dataTable[0]` and create chart but I am not able to find how to return multiple Json objects in one call and how to handle those in JQuery/Ajax.

One approach is to make separate for each chart controller and return Json objects but I don’t want to make multiple calls to Stored procedure.

Any suggestions how I can return multiple dataTable/or class objects from MVC to Ajax Call?

```
e.g: Each Json objects can have a same or different structure
DataTable 1: {Category: “A”, Points:20, Percentage:87} 
        {Category: “B”, Points:20, Percentage:87} 

DataTable 1: {Category: “A”, Spots:20, Percentage:87,ExtraInfo: “NA”} 
        {Category: “B”, Spots:20, Percentage:87,ExtraInfo: “NA”}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can only return one JSON string, so have a parameter per data table, eg. `[{ dt1: { /* stuff */ }, dt2: { /* stuff */ } }];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting you to try in this way

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Action()
    {
        MyClass objMyClass = new MyClass();
        objMyClass.lstTables = new List<System.Data.DataTable>();
        objMyClass.lstTables.Add(new System.Data.DataTable());
        objMyClass.lstTables.Add(new System.Data.DataTable());
        return Json(objMyClass);
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public List<System.Data.DataTable> lstTables { get; set; }
    }
```

Now you can pass n number of tables

Answer (score 0):

You can return array in one JSON object (do it in application or return one result obkect from database if you like), like:

```
{
  [
    {data for table 1},
    {data for table 2},
    ...
  ]
}
```

Or if it different types, like

```
{
  [
    {ChartType1: Type1, Data: {data for table 1}},
    {ChartType2: Type2, Data: {data for table 2}},
    ...
  ]
}
```